# Jordan matrices and isomorphisms

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

We just proved in class that if $A$ is a linear transformation of a finite dimensional $K$-vector space $V$ (where $K$ is algebraically closed), then there exists a basis of $V$ such that the matrix of $A$ relative to that basis is a Jordan matrix.

I was now wondering how I could prove the following theorem under the same circumstances where $V$ and $V'$ are the vector spaces of the same dimension and $A$ and $A'$ are linear transformations on these vector spaces:

$A$ and $A'$ have the same Jordan matrix iff there exists and isomorphism $f: V \rightarrow V'$ so that the following diagram is commutative:

[image]

Comment: That's obviously wrong: Take $V=V'\neq 0$, $A=0$ and $A'=\operatorname{id}_V$. Maybe you want your isomorphism $V\to V'$ to behave well with respect to $A$ and $A'$ somehow?

Comment: My bad, I found that there is a bit of a nuance to the theorem that i missed... I'll update the question

Comment: Maybe just take $f$ as the linear map that takes the first JB to the second? ;-)

Comment: @ancientmathematician That does seem to solve the problem, is it really that easy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B=\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ be a basis of $V$. When $f\colon V\to V'$ is an isomorphism satisfying $A'\circ f=f\circ A$, it follows that $B':=\{f(v_1),\dots,f(v_n)\}$ is a basis of $V'$ and the transformation matrices $[A]_{B,B}=[A']_{B',B'}$ are identical. In particular they have the same Jordan canonical form.

When $A$ and $A'$ have the same Jordan canonical forms, take Jordan bases $B=\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ of $V$ with respect to $A$ and $B'=\{v'_1,\dots,v'_n\}$ of $V'$ with respect to $A'$. Define $f\colon V\to V'$ by $f(v_i)=v'_i$ and note that this yields $A'\circ f=f\circ A$.

---

Note that this is just a corollary of matrices being similar iff they have the same JCF.

Comment: Wow it really is that simple! Thanks a bunch! Is there anything else I should do on my own to complete the proof or does this suffice?